# Table cross-referencing not matching table number

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, lncs

I am using the `llncs` document class and I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679720/286153) answer matching my required task. However, I use cross-referencing very often in my document, and I noticed this the table number cross-referenced does not match the actual table.

I reduce the code (from said answer here):

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}



\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}

\subsection{Sub-section I}
Checking cross-reference for Table \ref{tab:abc}   

  \title{Paper Title}
  
  \begin{table}[htp]
    \label{tab:abc} % <-  added by me
    \caption{Classification results of imbalance techniques}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l
        @{\hskip 1ex}
        *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
        @{\hskip 1ex}
        *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
        @{\hskip 1ex}
        *{5}{S[table-format=1.2]}
        @{}
      }
      \toprule
      TM &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{Recall} &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{F1-Score} \\
      \cmidrule(r{1ex}){2-6} \cmidrule(r{1ex}){7-11} \cmidrule{12-16}
      & {R} & {S} & {A} & {B} & {D}   & {R} & {S} & {A} & {B} & {D}   & {R} & {S} & {A} & {B} & {D}\\
      \midrule
      Walk & 0.88 & 0.78 & 0.65 & 0.59 & 0.45 & 0.38 & 0.73 & 0.95 & 0.83 & 0.57 & 0.52 & 0.07 & 0.22 & 0.66 & 0.88 \\
      Bike & 0.88 & 0.78 & 0.65 & 0.59 & 0.45 & 0.38 & 0.73 & 0.95 & 0.83 & 0.57 & 0.52 & 0.07 & 0.22 & 0.66 & 0.88 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}

    \medskip

    TM: Transportation mode

    R: RF; S: RF-SMOTEd; A: AdaBoost; B: SMOTEBoost; D: DECOC
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I want it to be (just) like this:

```
Checking cross-reference for Table 1.
```

Comment: label has to be after caption

Comment: Unrelated: I'd recommend to use a protected space: `Table~\ref{...}`. Loosely related: I'd even more recommend to use the `cleveref` package. With it you would have noticed that you don't reference the table but the subsection.